# How to keep new window from opening upon double click of a folder in XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

I am using Windows XP. Whenever I double click a folder, a new window pops up with the search companion in the left navigation panel. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call Dllregisterserver like so:

Start -> Run (or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>)

paste this and press enter:

```
regsvr32 /i shell32.dll
```

Comment: I concur with this one, it almost always fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

1. Open Windows Explorer.
2. Select Folders in the toolbar to change the navigation panel to folders or just click the search button again to remove it all together.
3. Then go to Tools > Folder Options and the View tab.
4. Click Apply to All Folders.

Next time you open the folder, it should be set to whatever you have chosen.

This may also reset other options you have set on a per folder basis.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Folder Options in the Control Panel. In the *General Tab* set Browse Folders as *'Open Each Folder in the Same Window*', press Apply and OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the steps outlined in this [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q321186).

> This problem occurs when you open the
>   Edit File Type dialog box for the
>   Drive or File Folder registered file
>   types. For example, this problem
>   occurs for folders if you complete the
>   following procedure:
>
> 1. Open the folder, and then click Folder Options on the Tools menu.
> 2. Click File Folder in the Register file types list, and then
>      click Advanced.
> 3. After you perform this procedure, the None setting is removed
>      from the value data for the Default
>      string value in the following registry
>      key:
>
>    `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`
>
>    NOTE: This problem occurs even if you do not create a new action,
>      edit existing actions, or change the
>      default action in the Edit File Type
>      dialog box.